# Scheduling Tasks at exact time in Android Oreo and above

Tags: android, location, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

Is there any way to schedule a task on Android (Oreo and Above)? I want to schedule location tracking start/stop event. Let's say start Location tracking at 9:00 AM Daily & Stop it 6:00 PM Daily. Please suggest a solution. Does the Alarm Manager help me with this?

Comment: Why can't you use `JobScheduler` and `WorkManager`

Comment: As I know they will not work on the Exact time. Will they work?

Comment: You can make it work using `OneTimeWorkRequest`

Answer (score 1):

If it supposed to be 9AM/6PM sharp `AlarmManager` is your friend as it can trigger alarm at exact time https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent).

With introduction of `Doze` mode and permission level changes on `JobScheduler` and `WorkManager` might be delayed even by 15 minutes but it is more flexible and scheduled jobs persist through system reboots.

Back to Android optimisation you should take in consideration fact that you can't have background service for location anymore and while implementing it pay attention to how you get it cause it might drain the battery fairly quickly.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. The best solution for me was to implement Firebase Messaging and send data notifications to device and then trigger some action in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` (e.g. get location and send it to server).
To schedule it from 9:00AM to 06:00PM I would use a cron job, that triggers the message in the firebase. Bonus feature - you can change/pause/start updating remotely (without app update).